# Using a SQL Server FILESTREAM GUID as a primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a simple table called `Photo` to store photos for people/groups defined in a `User` table. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server's [`FILESTREAM`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx) feature, since all other user data is already stored in SQL Server, and it makes more sense to me than programming a separate way to manually retrieve objects from the disk when they're directly related to entries in the database.

Each user can have only one photo associated with them at a time (for now, but this could change in the future), and `FILESTREAM` requires a `GUID` column to reference the files it stores to disk, so this is the model I've come up with for `Photo`:

```
UserID int NOT NULL UNIQUE
PhotoID uniqueidentifier ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL
PhotoBitmap varbinary(MAX) FILESTREAM NULL
```

My question is (if this model is correct for my application), should I use the `PhotoID` as the primary key, seeing as how it's already unique and is required? It seems to me that it would be simpler than creating a separate `INT` column just for the primary key, but I don't know if it is "correct".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally use `INT IDENTITY` for most of my primary and clustering keys.

You need to keep apart the **primary key** which is a logical construct - it uniquely identifies your rows, it has to be unique and stable and `NOT NULL`. A `GUID` works well for a primary key, too - since it's guaranteed to be unique. A `GUID` as your primary key is a good choice if you use SQL Server replication, since in that case, you need an uniquely identifying `GUID` column anyway.

The **clustering key** in SQL Server is a physical construct is used for the physical ordering of the data, and is a lot more difficult to get right. Typically, the *Queen of Indexing* on SQL Server, Kimberly Tripp, also requires a good clustering key to be unique, stable, as narrow as possible, and ideally ever-increasing (which a `INT IDENTITY` is).

See her articles on indexing here:

- [GUIDs as PRIMARY KEYs and/or the clustering key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)
- [The Clustered Index Debate Continues...](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx)
- [Ever-increasing clustering key - the Clustered Index Debate..........again!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx)
- [Disk space is cheap - that's **not** the point!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Disk-space-is-cheap.aspx)

and also see Jimmy Nilsson's [The Cost of GUIDs as Primary Key](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25862)

A `GUID` is a **really bad choice** for a clustering key, since it's wide, totally random, and thus leads to **bad index fragmentation** and poor performance. Also, the clustering key row(s) is also stored in each and every entry of each and every non-clustered (additional) index, so you really want to keep it small - `GUID` is 16 byte vs. `INT` is 4 byte, and with several non-clustered indices and several million rows, this makes a HUGE difference.

In SQL Server, your primary key is by default your clustering key - but it doesn't have to be. You can easily use a `GUID` as your NON-Clustered primary key, and an `INT IDENTITY` as your clustering key - it just takes a bit of being aware of it.